# Como calcular a média usando condições no SQL Server?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

A questão pede que eu mostre a quantidade de alunos com médias maiores que 7, menores que 7 ou iguais a 7 para algumas tabelas que eu tenho aqui. Mostrando dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como criar essa coluna de **Descrição**?

Comment: Vai ser algo parecido com: `SELECT CASE WHEN AVG(NOTA) > 7 THEN'Superior a 7' WHEN AVG(NOTA) = 7 THEN 'Igual a 7' ELSE ' Inferior a 7' END 'Desrição', COUNT(*)
FROM ALUNO`

Comment: Você pode fazer isso usando o CASE

Comment: @Marconi, eu não tenho o create aqui, pois as tabelas já estavam criadas quando fui resolver a questão (são tabelas imensas inclusive). Mas para mostrar o nome da classe e a quantidade de alunos com média acima de 7, devo fazer um join entre as tabelas cla_classe (que contém o nome da classe), ava_avaliacao, apa_aproveitamento_aluno (que contém as notas dos alunos) e alu_aluno (que possui as informações de cada aluno)

Comment: @M.Amaral Entendi, minha resposta ajuda?

Comment: @Marconi Testo daqui a pouco e dou um retorno

Comment: @M.Amaral editei a sua pergunta para abranger um pouco mais, sendo assim tornar mais acessível a futuros leitores.

Comment: @M.Amaral deu certinho?

Comment: deu certo sim, e depois também conseguindo fazer usando union e fazendo a coluna descrição no próprio select, simplesmente fazendo algo do tipo `select 'Superior a 7' Descrição,`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [AVG (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/avg-transact-sql)

> Retorna a média dos valores em um grupo. Os valores nulos são
> ignorados.

Como você não deu detalhes, presumo que seu `SQL` será algo do tipo:

```
SELECT CASE
   WHEN AVG(NOTA) > 7 THEN 'Superior a 7'
   WHEN AVG(NOTA) = 7 THEN 'Igual a 7'
   ELSE ' Inferior a 7'
   END 'Desrição',
   COUNT(*) Quantidade
FROM ALUNO
GROUP BY CLASSE
```

Comment: Faltou o `GROUP BY` por classe.